# Call Snippet From Jquery/Ajax MODx

Tags: javascript, jquery, modx, modx-revolution

I have a select element that does a post using jQuery on a change event, I was trying to post it to a snippet and get the results back, however it seems that if the snippet is called directly from javascript there will be no notion of the (`$modx`) object and i can't access the DB using PDO, my code is as follows:

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#camplist').change(function() {

        $.post('core/components/evoprograms/snippets/register-camp.php?action=getCamp&id=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
            $("camp-details").show();
            $('.result').html(data);
        });

    });

});
```

What's the right approach to do it?

Comment: If you tell us what the problem is, and maybe post some of the relevant html and php, it would be easier to come up with a solution. :)

Comment: the problem is simply doing an AJAX call from the modx front end and reveiveing and the call on the backendm the problem is that I am not able to call the snippet directly from the front end

Answer (score 2):

> $.post('core/components/evoprograms/snippets/register-camp.php

This is not good - you don't want anyone accessing anything under /core/*

Basically there are two ways:

1. The simplest way - create a resource (without any template) with only your snippet call in it as content (uncached!).   then do you $.post to that resource.
2. the revolution way (cleaner, better) - use your own connector (/assets/components/evoprograms/connector.php).   [see this](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/PHP+Coding+in+MODx+Revolution,+Pt.+III) for more info.  or just copy any existing connector and modify if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it other way like - you can submit the form on an `onchange` event and give the form `action` to call that snippet required...

For example see the below code:-

```html
<form action="[[!snippetname]]" method="POST">
  <h3>dropdown: 
    <select name="selection" onchange="this.form.submit();">
      <option>select</option>
      <option value="2">all</option>
     </select>
   </h3>
 </form>
```

And this doesn't need any javascript.

Comment: Actually 'this.form.submit()' is JavaScript ;^)

Answer (score 0):

Load the modx object in your core/components/evoprograms/snippets/register-camp.php script,

```
define('MODX_API_MODE', true); 
// Full path to the index
require_once('/path/to/modx/public_html/index.php');
$modx = new modX();
$modx->initialize('mgr');
//your post
$your post here = $_POST['register'];
```